# Docker image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 does not build on windows

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-8.0

GIVEN I use Window 11 with Docker Desktop switched to windows container

WHEN I try to build official ASP.NET Core 8 runtime image

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
```

I get error:

> no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.22621 in the manifest list entries

The same happens when I try to build the image in production VM with Windows Server 2022 Standard

Comment: At least they recognized the new/updated error message is less-than-helpful :D 
`Unfortunately, with this plan, Windows users will get an even less user-friendly error message.`
https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/4492

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a breaking change in .NET 8 Docker containers - [Multi-platform container tags are Linux-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/multi-platform-tags):

> The .NET 8 multi-platform container tags have been updated to be Linux-only. This means that the `latest`, `<major>.<minor>`, and `<major>.<minor>.<patch>` tags are Linux-only going forward.
> Starting in .NET 8, the `8.0` tag will only retrieve a Linux-based image.

So `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0` is a Linux-based image, specifically Debian 12:

| Tags | Dockerfile | OS Version | Last Modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8.0.0-bookworm-slim-amd64, 8.0-bookworm-slim-amd64, 8.0.0-bookworm-slim, 8.0-bookworm-slim, 8.0.0, 8.0, latest | Dockerfile | Debian 12 | 11/21/2023 |

Try using one of the Windows-based tags:

For example `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022` from:

##### Windows Server Core 2022 amd64 Tags

| Tag | Dockerfile | Last Modified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8.0.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022, 8.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022 | Dockerfile | 11/14/2023 |
| 7.0.14-windowsservercore-ltsc2022, 7.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022 | Dockerfile | 11/14/2023 |
| 6.0.25-windowsservercore-ltsc2022, 6.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022 | Dockerfile | 11/14/2023 |

See more:

- [ASP.NET Core Runtime Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet/) page (scroll down for the options for different images)
- [PR for docs](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/38638) which mentions that corresponding images should be used since .NET 8.

Comment: Seems to work, but the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows&pivots=dotnet-8-0#create-the-dockerfile) states we should use the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0` image - without the OS postfix. It worked for aspnet:7.0

Comment: @Liero see the update. There was a breaking change in .NET 8